# Seaborn heatmap getting cropped

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

Not getting proper size of seaborn heatmap of a correlation matrix. The plot is seemed to be cropped from top and bottom. Here's the code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

np.random.seed(42)
data = np.random.randint(1, 1000, 100 * 3).reshape(-1, 3)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['x', 'y', 'z'])
corrMatrix = df.corr()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5))
sns.heatmap(corrMatrix, annot=True, linewidths=.5, cmap="YlGnBu", square=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: What's your matplotlib version? [This was an issue with matplotlib v3.1.1](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/14675), you may need to upgrade matplotlib

Comment: Correct, using v3.1.1, let me update and see. Thanks!

Comment: With higher version of matplotlib it is OK now. Cheers!